# ICN Entry Template Cached

Tags: browser-cache, ibm-content-navigator

We have an Entry Template created in ICN and populating a couple of fields through a plugin (logged in user email and unique case number) when it is opened.

Everything works fine at first instance and users are able to add the document to FileNet. If the user clicks the template again, the template is rendered with the same previous case number. But when they clear cache and load the template, a new case number is assigned through the custom plug-in. I was reading the article @ https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEUEX_2.0.2/com.ibm.installingeuc.doc/eucts010.html and got to know that, ICN caches Entry Template on the web browser for IBM® Content Navigator. Is there a way to stop this?

I have been going through the documentation but can't find a way to stop this.

Comment: I don't know of a feature to disable caching. But, understanding you want to assign a unique number to a document property upon creation, have you considered the following alternatives: Using a RequestFilter (ICN plugin feature), or a filenet p8 synchronous event action / preprocessor?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm using response filter to populate the case number field. Let me check preprocessor